# Why my custom cursor adapter is not working? Same code was working fine when used with ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Aim of my program is to store data in SQLite database and then use that database in list view.
I have provided the codes ( deleted some unnecessary codes) below.
I have inserted successfully some dummy data in database.
Layout for custom adapter is also working properly.
My app is crashing when creating the object of Timetable adapted.
I have tried all the way which I can do, but not working.

If need some more information please let me know.

In MainActivity.java

```
    TimeTableDBHelper timeTableDbHelper = new TimeTableDBHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = timeTableDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    db = timeTableDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] columns = {TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME,TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME,
                            TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATE,
                            TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH
                           };

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TimeTableContract.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
//My app is crashing after this line only
    TimeTableAdapter adapter = new TimeTableAdapter(this, cursor);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView1);
   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
cursor.close();
```

TimetableAdapter.java

```
public class TimeTableAdapter extends CursorAdapter
{

public TimeTableAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
    super(context,cursor,0);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent)
{

    return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.table_list_view, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
{
int startColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME);
    String time1 = cursor.getString(startColumnIndex);
    int endColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME);
    String time2 = cursor.getString(endColumnIndex);
    int dateColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATE);
    String date = cursor.getString(dateColumnIndex);
    int monthColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH);
    String month = cursor.getString(monthColumnIndex);

    TextView startTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.start_time);
    TextView endTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.end_time);
    TextView tuitorName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tuitor_name);
    TextView subject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subject);
    TextView remarks = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remarks);
    TextView dateMonth = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);

    startTime.setText(time1);
    endTime.setText(time2);
    tuitorName.setText("Tutor");
    subject.setText("subject");
    remarks.setText("remarks...");
    dateMonth.setText(date+", " + month);
}
```

Contract class

```
public  class TimeTableContract 
{
// Make constructor private do that it does not initiatted accidently
private TimeTableContract()
{};
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "time_table";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME = "start_time";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME = "end_time";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_DATE = "date";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_MONTH = "month";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ID = "_id";

}
```

Creating table in database by following code ( by the way there is no problem with my database helper class)

```
"CREATE TABLE " + TimeTableContract.TABLE_NAME + " ( " + 
                    TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME + " TEXT," +
                    TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME + " TEXT,"+
                    TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATE + " TEXT,"+
                    TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH + " TEXT)";
```

Comment: Because I wants more control over adapter.

Comment: Whatever. But I don't want to get into trouble later by porting code from simple cursor adaptor to cursor adapter.

Comment: there any problem with my codes.

Comment: But I had already passed the cursor to the adapter. So closing it will not effect the adapter I think!

Comment: Btw, I will think about SimpleCursor too.

Comment: Hey @psking If I use SimpleCursorAdapter, how can I concatenat strings from two column and show it in a text view which I am passing in 'int[] to'.

Comment: Yes! I checked by removing the cursor.close(), but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "_id" column in your cursor here:

```
    String[] columns = {TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_START_TIME,
                        TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_END_TIME,
                        TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_DATE,
                        TimeTableContract.COLUMN_NAME_MONTH
                       };
```

It's an android convention that you must include "_id" column in your cursor if you are working with CursorAdapters and ListViews or else they won't work.

When you implement onItemClick() method for your listview, you will get that same _id as an argument named `long id`

```
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, **long id**)
```

Comment: Thanks @kush gupt, Now my app is running, but I have to remove the cursor.close() statement ( in ActivityMain.java > last line ). Then where should I place this statement.

Comment: @vivekkumar The Cursor and the database must be closed after we have finished with them in order to release their resources. We usually close them as soon as we are done with them, but the case with adapters is slightly different. Cursor adapter needs the Cursor to stay open till it requires more data from it. Consider a condition; you set the adapter to a listview and then you immediately close the cursor,  and listview was able to populate first 20 views, now the user scroll down, and listview needs to populate more views so it looks for data from the cursor, but the cursor is dead.

Comment: I am not arguing, but I want to know that, if we have already passed the cursor when calling the custom adapter, then why the adapter is dependent on original cursor.

Comment: @vivekkumar So, in such special case (the use of cursor with adapters) we must not close them immediately. I prefer closing both database and the cursor in the onDestroy() method.

Comment: @vivekkumar because listview don't read complete data  from the cursor at once, they read in segments and when it is required(like scroll down event).

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much kush gupt for your kind support. Have a nice day.